# How to join 3 tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables,one for Study and the others are Travel and Country.Study. 
`Study`  table contains `StudyID,StartDate,EndDate,CountryID` and set `StudyID` as `primary key`.

`Travel` table contains `TravelID,StudyID,CountryID,TravelStartDate,TravelEndDate` ,`TravelID` as `Primary key` and `StudyID` as `Foreign key`.

`Country` table contains `CountryID,CountryCode,CountryName, CountryID` as `primary key`.

I want to get `CountryName` like `"CountryCode+' - '+CountryName as CountryName".`

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
            Study.CountryID
                       ,Travel.CountryID
                       ,StartDate   
                       ,EndDate
                       ,TravelStartDate,TravelEndDate,
               , CountryCode+' - '+CountryName as CountryName,              

                      FROM dbo.Study left join  dbo.Countries
                      on 
                      Study.CountryID=Countries.CountryID
                     left join Travel 
                      on 
                     Travel.StudyID=Study.StudyID
```

I want to display the `CountryName` for `Travel` and `Study`. How can I display one country for travel and one for study ?

Answer (score 0):

Also because you are joining study on country and then on travel which means they will always be the same.

The below should work assuming there is a value in each of the tables. This is hugely untested, but should point you in the right direction. I think the cross apply requires SQL server 2005 or above.

```
    ;with
GetStudyCountry as
(
select a.countryCode, a.countryName
FROM dbo.countries a
LEFT JOIN dbo.study b on a.countryid = b.countryid
)
,GetTravelCountry as
(
select a.countryCode, a.countryName
FROM dbo.countries a
LEFT JOIN dbo.travel b on a.countryid = b.countryid
)
select a.CountryID ,b.CountryID ,a.StartDate, a.enddate ,b.TravelStartDate ,b.TravelEndDate, GetTravelCountry.CountryCode + '-' + GetTravelCountry.CountryName as TravelCountryName, GetStudyCountry.CountryID + '-' GetStudyCountry.CountryID as StudyCountryName
from dbo.study a
cross apply dbo.travel b
cross apply GetTravelCountry c
cross apply GetStudyCountry d
```

Answer (score 0):

You are joining all the three tables with one another which means they will always be the same.
I guess you are looking for this result.
You can try this :

```
SELECT  A.CountryID ,B.TravelID,A.StartDate ,A.EndDate ,B.StartDate ,B.EndDate ,C.CountryCode + ' - ' + C.CountryName AS CountryName
FROM    STUDY A
        INNER JOIN TRAVEL B ON A.StudyID = B.StudyID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Country C ON A.CountryID = C.CountryID
```